# Декодирование xml тегов

Tags: xml, ajax, javascript

Php скрипт возвращает XML.

```
$text2 = "Тут текст";
$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"cp1251\"?><maindata>
    <data1>Text 1</data1>" .
    "<data2>$text2</data2>" .
    "</maindata>";
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $xml;
```

Через JS получаю DOM объект и работаю с ним. Но если в переменной **$text2** будет html-теги то парсер подумает, что это тоже чать xml и не правильно построит DOM.

Как указать, все что находится между тегами data2 будет просто текстом?

Comment: Я бы так и сделал, но мне этот html нужен целый, что бы потом его вставить в тело html документа и получить некий список, который сгенерировал сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net//manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php Может попробовать тупо кодировать `$text2`?

[Новая идея](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

> All text in an XML document will be parsed by the parser.
> But text inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.

Это, вроде, должно вам подойти.